# Youtube Video Parser iOS

Tags: ios, video, youtube, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to parse youtube link and play on MPMoviePlayerViewController.

I am just following this link and I can parse successfully with their example youtube link.
 https://github.com/hellozimi/HCYoutubeParser 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8To-6VIJZRE

However, the problem is that I can't parse other youtube URL like this

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ndy1J859n5I

Is it because of video duration? I would like to know how to solve this.

Code

```
// Gets an dictionary with each available youtube url
NSDictionary *videos = [HCYoutubeParser h264videosWithYoutubeURL:[NSURL     URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8To-6VIJZRE"]];

// Presents a MoviePlayerController with the youtube quality medium
MPMoviePlayerViewController *mp = [[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[videos objectForKey:@"medium"]]] autorelease];
[self presentModalViewController:mp animated:YES];

// To get a thumbnail for an image there is now a async method for that
[HCYoutubeParser thumbnailForYoutubeURL:url
                      thumbnailSize:YouTubeThumbnailDefaultHighQuality
                      completeBlock:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {
if (!error) {
    self.thumbailImageView.image = image;
}
else {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
}];
```

Comment: What parsing is being done? I don't see any parsing. What's the difference between those two Youtube links (besides the id)? What problem are you having with the 2nd URL?

Comment: Yes. I can see video playing when I use first link. But if I use other, I can't play video. Really strange. I am not sure what happen.

Comment: they are getting urls for medium quality and hd quality differently...i think if the video doesn't have those paths ..it doesn't play the video.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to successfully send videos from a class in Parse.com to an app. Is this what you are trying to do? If so, the above code is completely incorrect.